# Отследить приложение, которое создает каталоги в Android

Tags: android, файлы

Возможно ли определить приложение, которое создает каталоги в Android? Если да - как это сделать?

Comment: что значит в вашем понятии "отследить"? и при чем здесь android разработка? или вы хотите монитор приложений сделать?

Comment: Да, отчасти вы правы. Хочется разобрать подобное приложение и посмотреть на алгоритм его работы. Однако не удалось найти чего-то подобного. Ну, знаете, "Process Monitor" только под Android.

Comment: Попробуйте воспользоваться inotify API, которе доступно с Linux 2.6.13 - https://github.com/jrummyapps/inotify-android-tools

Answer (score 1):

Честно говоря довольно интересная и нестандартная задача, как для меня)) Может тот кто уже много лет мобильной разработкой, придумает полностью весь процесс создания такого приложения, но честно говоря я могу только рассказать свое виденье этой задачи и тот алгоритм который я бы использовал для решения подобного рода задания.

Начнем с того наверное что вам нужно получить доступ ко всем установленным приложениям на телефоне. У вас должен получится примерно такой же список как и например в разделе настроек телефона. Следующим шагом вам нужно будет отсеять из списка те приложения которые не имеют разрешения на доступ к памяти устройства, например если у приложения есть только разрешение на отправку смс, или что-то в этом роде. Вам я думаю придется вытащить в массив все разрешения, которые имеют ваши приложения из списка, и дальше уже фильтровать. В итоге у вас должен получится еще один список, но поменьше.

Теперь у вас есть приложения которые могу создавать каталоги в памяти. А дальше вам уже решать что делать с этими приложениями. Если вы хотите создавать историю или хронологию доступа к памяти, то вам нужно будет каким-то образом получить историю получения разрешения у системы на доступ к памяти устройства, и дальше уже смотреть идентификатор приложения, смотреть по какому пути он что делалось в директории по этому пути.

Есть конечно и другой вариант: вы можете мониторить создание новых каталогов, и дальше уже смотреть какие приложения какой каталог создавали.

В любом случае вам нужно двигаться в сторону работы с файловой системой, работой с приложениями и их данными и требованиями. Надеюсь я правильно объяснил стратегию разработки такого приложения, и меня не начнут сейчас закидывать помидорами)) Удачи :)

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый